# Style a specific item in ListView

Tags: android, listview

How do I style a specific item in a `ListView`? For example let's say
`if(text in list view.equals("ABC"))`, then ABC should be `bold, have a size of 16sp` etc. I am creating this `ListView` from a String array.

Here's my code:

```
public class IngSearch extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {

    ListView lv;
    String list[] = {"123", "QAZ", ""edc", "ABC"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ing_search); 
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
```

And in this list I want to apply a style like this to ABC

```
<style name="abcStyle">
    <item name = "android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
</style>
```

Thanks

Comment: here is the tutorial that you can follow to achieve this http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-listview

Comment: That site doesn't really answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is solution
Firstly, you need to custom your `listview adapter` then inside `getView(...)` you can set the style for each specific textview

```
      public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
               ...
            }

            @Override
            public codeLearnChapter getItem(int arg0) {
                ...
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int arg0) {
               ...
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
             ...
             TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
             if(your condition){ 
                   textViewTitle.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.abcStyle); // change your textview style here
             }else if(...){
                   textViewTitle.setTextAppearance(// another style );
             }else{
                  textViewTitle.setTextAppearance(// another style );
             }
        }
}
```

Hope this help